# Calling async method in ngInit not working in Angular 14

Tags: javascript, angular, async-await, angularjs-ng-init, ng-init

I have a problem with calling an “async” method in “ngInit” method in angular 14
here is the method I want to call when component initialized:

```
async setInterfaceDatatableHeaders() {
    var bankName = await GetTranslatedValue(this.translate, "SUPPLIERMANAGEMENT.Bank”)
      .then(res => {
        return res;
      });
    var accountOwnerName = await GetTranslatedValue(this.translate, "GENERAL.AccountOwnerName”)
      .then(res => {
        return res;
      });
    var interfaceBankID = await GetTranslatedValue(this.translate, "SUPPLIERMANAGEMENT.InterfaceBankID”)
      .then(res => {
        return res;
      });
    var accountOwnerTel = await GetTranslatedValue(this.translate, "GENERAL.AccountOwnerTel”)
      .then(res => {
        return res;
      });

    this.interfaceDatatableHeaders = [
      new DataTableHeaderDTO('BankName', bankName, 'text'),
      new DataTableHeaderDTO('AccountOwnerName', accountOwnerName, 'text'),
      new DataTableHeaderDTO('InterfaceBankID', interfaceBankID, 'text'),
      new DataTableHeaderDTO('AccountOwnerTel', accountOwnerTel, 'text'),
    ]
  }
```

When I call it directly in ngInit, method not calling and not working
but if I surround the method with a “setTimeout” function, it will work properly

This works :

```
setTimeout(async () => {
      await this.setInterfaceDatatableHeaders();
    }, 0);
```

This NOT work with this way of calling, even if I set async for my “ngInit” method:

```
await this.setInterfaceDatatableHeaders();
```

How can I fix this without using “setTimeout” in “NgInit” ???

Comment: @GaëlJ No, I've seen that before and it's not what I'm looking for

Comment: Have you declared `ngOnInit` with `async`?

Comment: @GaëlJ yes, It's not working with async ````ngOnInit```` neither

Comment: Show us the complete code you tried